# promise rejection on setting up pgPromise wrapper for postgesql db: using wrong db name

Tags: database, reactjs, promise, graphql, express-graphql

I'm trying to set up a react app that uses graphql with a postgresql database. Right now im only trying to set up a pg adaptor to my existing postgresql db that I host locally. When running `node pgAdaptor.js` i get a rejected promise saying that the db does not exist, but the name it says doesnt exist is the username, and not the correct db name, which is 'filter'.

I want to know what could possibly cause node to try and use a username as a database name??

I am using the dotenv node package to read in the db properties into process.env, and i then use these to configure the server correctly, yet it still tries to connect to the same username. Even when i change the config in the .env file.

pgAdaptor.js:

```
require ('dotenv').config ();
const pgPromise = require ('pg-promise');

const pgp = pgPromise ({}); // Empty object means no additional config required

const config = {
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
  user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
};

const db = pgp (config);

exports.db = db;

db.one ('select * from users').then (res => {
  console.log (res);
});
```

db.env:

```
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=filter
POSTGRES_USER=morbidmerve
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
```

error:

```
(node:2449) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: database "morbidmerve" does not exist
    at Connection.parseE (/Users/morbidmerve/dev/test/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:601:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/morbidmerve/dev/test/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:398:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/morbidmerve/dev/test/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:120:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:17)
(node:2449) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:2449) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

when i test the pgAdaptor.js functionality i simply run

```
node pgAdaptor.js
```

I can confirm that the database `filter` exists and contains at least one record on each table.

This is supposed to work according to the tutorial found at https://blog.harveydelaney.com/setting-up-graphql-express-and-postgresql/ .

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Re-check what's really in your `config` object, because this doesn't add up.

Comment: bingo! thanks for the suggestion....the config object contains a bunch of undefined values. You suppose that if the config object contains the right values then it should work fine?

Comment: Yes. And when config contains undefined values, those are replaced from the defaults - `pgp.pg.defaults`. That's what you are probably getting now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vitaly-t's comment on my question I found the problem:

The dotenv package was failing to read in the configs into process.env because the file wasnt named '.env' explicitly but rather only had a .env extension. i.e. mine was `db.env` which isn't a valid config file name apparently. Hence, after changing the file name to literally `.env` the dotenv package read in the configs perfectly.

Also stack overflow is awesome!